# Prove if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $f(a) > 0$, $\exists$ interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $\forall x \in I, F(x) > 0$

Tags: continuity, proof-writing

Prove if $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $f(a) > 0$, there exists an interval $I$ containing $a$ such that $\forall x \in I, F(x) > 0.$

Comment: I used the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity and let $\epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}$ and went from there to $|f(x)-f(a)|<\frac{f(a)}{2}$ and expanded the absolute value, and got a full proof. I want to see other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because $f$ is continuous at $a$, for any given $\epsilon >0$, we can find some $\delta >0$ such that:
$$
|x - a|< \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)|< \epsilon \implies f(a) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(a) + \epsilon
$$

Take $\epsilon$ sufficiently small so that $f(a) - \epsilon >0$ then we see that there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-a| < \delta$ implies:
$$
0 < f(a) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(a) + \epsilon
$$
So $f$ takes on positive values for all the points $|x-a|< \delta$ which is all points in the interval $ I = (a-\delta,a+\delta)$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If we take $$\epsilon=\frac {f (a)}{2} $$

then there will exist $\eta>0$ such that
for all $x\in (a-\eta,a+\eta)=I $

$$f (a)-\frac {f (a)}{2}<f (x)<f (a)+\frac {f (a)}{2} $$

and
$$f (x)>\frac {f (a)}{2}>0$$